# Simple Random Walk with equal probability of +1 and -1.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk, random

You have 1D random Walk, with +1 of probability 0.5, and -1 of probability 0.5.

What is the probability that you will reach +10 but never exceed -5?

---

Attempt:
The probability of getting +10 is easy, it is just 0.5^10. But I don't know how to factor in the -5 part.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I remember we used to draw a graph, and there is multiple ways to get to the step =10. This part is easy. But now, the question is that I simply don't know how to factor in the the -5 part.

Comment: Presumably your random walk starts from $0$.  If so, $\ 0.5^{10}\ $ is the probability of getting to $+10$ *in the first $10$ steps*, *not* the probability of *eventually* reaching $+10$.

Comment: I think the question intends to ask "What is the probability of reaching $+10$ before $-6$"

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  However, the question also contains the statement "The probability of getting +10 is easy, it is just 0.5^10", which, unless I'm misunderstanding  what it's referring to, is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take a look at [Gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

Comment: yup, forgot about this. I learnt gambler's ruin long time ago. Thanks